# How to connect GTK3 button click events to callbacks

Tags: python, application-development, gtk3, glade

So, I'm developing my 1st app with GTK3 and I don't know how to link my buttons with their respective defs. Can anyone post a tutorial, an example or some docs?

Using next things for developing my app:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS totally updated
- Python 2.7.3
- Obviously, GTK+ 3
- Glade 3.12.1

The app which I'm developing is [Virtuam](https://launchpad.net/virtuam) (candidate at the App Showdown!)

Comment: Are you trying to link the button to the event callback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this [example on how to connect events to callbacks in Gtk 3 and Python](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#extended-example). In short, you use the `connect()` method to connect a **signal** name (which is emitted when an event such as a button click occurs) to a **callback**, which is the function that will handle your event.

```
def __init__(self):
    # Other initialization code

    # We create a button
    self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Click Here")
    # We connect the 'clicked' signal to the callback
    self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
    # This function will be called whenever the user presses the button
    print "Hello World"
```

You can also watch the [Gtk3 Introduction Workshop video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwRsZuIaCOM&t=2m30s) that is part of the [Ubuntu App Showdown](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown).

If you're using Glade, you will need to make to make sure that the `on_<name-of-your-button>_clicked()` callback is defined in the code as a method of your window.

If you're using **Quickly**, that's all you'll need to worry about.

Otherwise, you'll need to manually connect the signal to the callback. You've got two options:

- Do it in the code with `self.builder.get_object('name-of-your-button').connect()` - assuming `builder` is the name of your `Gtk.Builder()` in which you've loaded your Glade UI.
- Do it with Glade looking at the properties of your button, choosing the signals tab and then writing the name of your callback in the 'clicked' signal.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, David... pero igualmente, estoy usando Glade para crear la interfaz, así que no funciona.

Comment: No worries, it should equally work with Glade. I've added an additional note on how to do that with Glade.

Comment: But I've done the links with a dictionary, instead of using that...

Comment: And it works! That's why I typed in the title (closed)

Comment: Now I need help with this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/153788/how-can-i-set-a-spin-button